How many random bidirectional edges do we need to fully connect a graph with $V$ vertices?
Given an empty graph with $V$ vertices. 
For each vertex we pick one random vertex and connect them with a bidirectional edge. (could also be connected to itself) 
After done this for every vertex we start over again and add a 2nd edge and so on.
We stop if the graph is fully connected, so every vertex can reach every other vertex over some path.
I) What is the expected value for the number of such edges $E_{ord}(e)$ needed to be added to fully connect  a graph of size $V$?
II) How does it change if we instead pick a random pair of vertices  and connect them with a  bidirectional edge. (instead of doing it ordered)    What is the expected number of such random edges $E_{rand}(e)$ for a fully connected graph of size $V$?
I'm looking for an approximation formula for large $V$. 
No proof required.

I did some experiments for small $V$ with calculating the mean out of 1000 trials.



$V$
$E_{ord}(e)$
$E_{rand}(e)$

$V$
$E_{rand}(e)$
$E_{ord}(e)$




1
1
1

16
19.651
28.791


2
1.974
2.006

25
30.735
49.568


3
3.491
3.812

32
39.213
66.757


4
4.875
5.486

50
60.467
113.955


5
6.199
7.242

64
77.693
154.242


6
7.57
8.729

75
90.708
186.919


7
8.9
10.792

100
121.952
259.918


8
9.964
12.473

128
151.462
348.074


9
11.2
14.365

150
179.87
423.287


10
12.51
16.453

200
240.535
589.602




For those examples we can make up a formula for the mean edges count needed:
If we pick and connect them in order $E_{ord}(e)$:
$$E_{ord}(e) \approx V \cdot 1.2$$
If we pick and connect them in random pairs $E_{rand}(e)$:
$$E_{rand}(e) \approx \approx V \cdot 2.7$$
For $E_{rand}(e)$ the factor seem to increase with higher $V$. Can we approximate it better?
But does this also hold for a large vertices count $V$?
(looking for an answer for $V \in [10^{35},10^{80}]$)

Despite we are adding an edge for every vertices the resulting $E_{ord}(e)$ are lower than expected beforehand. I might have done some mistake in my example calculation program.
Look those numbers plausible to you?

Edit: 
According to comments $E_{ord}$ seems to be correct or at least not far away from the correct equation.
Remaining question: How does it behave for $E_{rand}$ if we add an edge in between two random vertices on each step? It looks like the factor grows with higher $V$. Can we approximate $E_{rand}(e)$ better for higher $V$?

These do not seem lower than expected. A random mapping graph on $n$ vertices (what we get after we add one edge from every vertex) is known to have around $\frac12 \log n$ components, and a random $2$-out graph (what we get if we keep going until we add two edges from every vertex) is known to be not just connected but $2$-connected with high probability. So it makes sense that we stop somewhere between $n$ and $2n$ edges, closer to $n$ than $2n$.

Also, doing $1000$ trials with $10000$ vertices gives the same behavior; the average number of edges needed is $12042.6$ and the median number is $10996.5$.

@MishaLavrov looks like my implementation or my 12 year old computer has some poor performance. Testing it with 200 already took multiple minutes.

Algorithmically, the gold standard here is to do something like union-find so that if it takes $m$ edges to win, we only need to do $m$ operations. (I was too lazy to do this.) A second-best option if you're using a library function for testing connectivity is to do binary search on the minimum number of edges required, so that you only have to call the library function $O(\log n)$ instead of $O(n)$ times.

As a partial answer, $E_{\text{rand}}(e)$ is a well-known problem, first considered by Erdős and Rényi in the paper On the evolution of random graphs. They show that, starting from $n$ isolated vertices, the expected number of random edges necessary to connect the graph is $\frac12 n \log n$. What's more, if we set out to add $\frac12n \log n + yn$ edges, where $y$ is a fixed but not necessarily positive constant, then as $n \to \infty$ the probability that this will be enough approaches $e^{-e^{-2y}}$.
(Erdős and Rényi assume that no edge will be selected twice, and no loops are selected; however, if we sample from all $n^2$ pairs of endpoints at each step, the difference will not be noticed after only $\frac12 n \log n$ edges, anyway.)
In fact, there is a reason underlying the value $\frac12 n \log n$: it comes from the associated balls into bins problem problem where, in order for the graph to be connected, every vertex has to be picked as an endpoint at least once. In almost all cases, once the last isolated vertex gets picked as an endpoint, that's the point at which the graph becomes connected.
This also explains why $E_{\text{ord}}(e)$ is smaller: here, we are guaranteed that every vertex will be an endpoint of at least one edge after the first $n$ steps. The specific problem here either hasn't been considered before, or isn't well-known enough for me to have heard of it, but two special cases of it have:

If we look at what happens after $n$ steps (where we've looked at every vertex once), this is the graph of a random mapping; these are well-studied but generally not connected yet.
If we look at what happens after $2n$ steps (where we've looked at every vertex twice), this is a random 2-out graph; with probability tending to $1$ as $n \to \infty$, these are not just connected but $2$-connected.


Thanks again. Interesting how it is connected to other subjects. $\frac{1}{2} n \log(n)$
looks similar to the approximation for
Coupon collector problem If we transform it to $\frac{1}{2} n (\log(n)+0.5772)$ it approximates my test results even better.

It is exactly the coupon collector problem. (I linked to balls into bins, but those are essentially the same for the question we're considering.) Each vertex is a coupon, each edge is a cereal box with two random coupons in it, and we're trying to collect every coupon so that we have no isolated vertices. (There are other ways for the graph to be disconnected, but they're much less likely.)
